# how to change textfield x and y location and when edit is begin it's go back to normal location

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, macos

When i press button textfield frame location should changed [ex: (0,0) to (50,50)]. That code work's perfectly. But if i try to type in textfield it's go back to same frame location [0,0]

and this is my code

```
(IBAction)Buttonname:(id)sender
{
CGRect newframeTextfield = textfiledname.frame;
newframeTextfield.origin.y = 365;
textfiledname.frame = newframeTextfield;
}
```

And this is previous position

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    CGRect oldTextfieldframe = textfiledname.frame;
    oldTextfieldframe.origin.y = 333;
    oldTextfieldframe.origin.x = 50;
    textfiledname.frame = oldTextfieldframe;
}
```

and i am also using scrollview and automatic textfield move up when keyboard appear.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
        if (textField == textfiledname)
        {
            [Scrolview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 210) animated:YES];
            Scrolview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 900); // there is submit button in bottom so scroll up to submit when keyboard appear. Otherwise (320,568) using in other function
        }
}
```

and Advance Thanks... :)

Comment: Not clear. Can you explain what is your problem.

Comment: This is because of auto layout. You should not change the position by setting frames, you should modify the constraints instead. Anything that causes the view to redraw (like typing in the text field) will cause the view to move back to the position determined by its constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by Auto layout being enabled. If you are not particular about using Auto layout, then disable the 'Use Auto Layout' and 'Use size classes' options in IB.
If you want to continue using auto layout, you can try adding the missing constraints. The option can be accessed via 'Resolve Auto layout issues' button in IB